# How do I move the pivot point of a given object manually, using the blue/green/red arrows?

Tags: interface

So I want to not just center the pivot to the Mesh (which was possible using this menu) [image: a picture of the Object->Transform Menu button next to the Object Mode button on the bottom of Blender 2.9] but also to the bottom of the object, where it touches the grid. How do I do this manually or by entering values by hand into a box?

Comment: About entering values by hand: "N-panel" provides coordinates for 3D cursor, once you've entered desired numbers, choose "Origin to 3D Cursor".

Comment: You could use the way Bigfoot Blondy provides or use a slightly easier method in fact (mostly possible)...
Choose the vertice (vertex) where You want to add the Origin in edit mode. You could also choose more vertices and use the **center of the selection**. Now continue with his step 2 and 3 - DONE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I can see is so:

1. Create an empty and move it to the position of where you want the object origin
2. Press Shift S --> Cursor to selected
3. Select your object and go to: Object --> Transform --> Origin to 3D cursor

Ta Da,
Magic :-)

Hope I helped and best of luck,

BFB

Answer (score 0):

if you open a console and run this command you'll move the cursor to the center of the scene, so you can set manually were you want the cursor to be by canging x y z values

import bpy # in case you want to make it a scipt

```
x,y,z= 0,0,0          # change the 0 's here to your custom position 
bpy.context.scene.cursor_location = (x, y, z)
```

:)